# Parallel payment with express checkout not happening in lightbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal

I'm trying to get parallel payments with express checkout working in a lightbox.  Here's what I have in the form:

```
<a href='#' id='make-payment-btn'>Make payment</a>
<form>
...
</form>

<script>
var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({
trigger:null,
expType:'instant'
});
</script>
```

Once anchor tag is clicked, the form data is submitted to the view (I'm using Django) using Ajax.  The view returns the following output which I add to the existing DOM:

```
<script>
dg.startFlow('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

I get an in-page pop-up (the lightbox I presume) from PayPal that says 'Please continue your purchase in the secure window we opened. If you don't see it, click the button below.'  and a pop-up, which Chrome initially blocked, that allows me to login and review the order.  All the interaction goes inside the pop-up.  Nothing occurs in the lightbox.  I even have to enter my password each time; if I only make a single payment, PayPal automatically logs me in, but the workflow still happens in the pop-up.

Is this expected behavior?  Would using adaptive payments for parallel payments give different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this works as design.  All the login and payment is supposed to happen in the minibrowser pop-up.